# Explode em Delphi

Tags: delphi

Tenho um arquivo txt em que os dados são salvos da seguinte forma:

> 00:46:30@21/08/2014@Carlos dos Santos@São Paulo

No PHP eu usaria o `explode` para transformar cada dado antes do "@" em colunas.

Como faço isso em delphi ? Preciso que cada dado separado @ vire uma coluna, assim eu posso colocá-los em um LISTVIEW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um possível *reparo técnico*<sup>1</sup> é usar uma TStringlist:

```
var
   Colunas : TStringlist;

begin
   Colunas := TStringlist.Create;
   Colunas.Text := StringReplace('00:46:30@21/08/2014@Carlos dos Santos@São Paulo',
      '@',Char(13)+Char(10),[rfReplaceAll]);
```

A TStringlist usa internamente a sequência `CR` `LF` para separar os ítens, por isso o código acima transforma uma linha longa em vários ítens separados, ao trocar a `@` pela sequência `CR` `LF`

**Edit**: Como bem lembrado pelo [Edgar Muniz Berlinck](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/405/), a TStringList tem uma propriedade para quebrar a *string* por outros delimitadores, ficando desta forma:

```
var
   Colunas : TStringlist;

begin
   Colunas := TStringlist.Create;
   Colunas.Delimiter := '@';
   Colunas.DelimitedText := Linhas[i];
```

<sub>1. gambiarra</sub>

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. Não entendi uma coisa, como eu vou usar isso ? tipo eu queria usar da seguinte forma $coluna1, $coluna2, para cada texto antes do @.

Comment: obrigado. Lembrando que eu tenho um arquivo chamado cliente.txt e dentro dele várias linhas dessa. Se puder me ajudar com isso também eu agradeço, ele deve percorrer todo esse arquivo.

Comment: @user7605 para ler o arquivo linha a linha eu acho que é melhor fazer uma pergunta separada.

Comment: posso testar aqui já ?

Comment: deu certinho manualmente. Agora preciso fazer através da leitura de um arquivo txt, devo fazer outra pergunta ?

Comment: @user7605 eu acho melhor, só pra não misturar os dois assuntos. Assim essa sua pergunta fica pra quem no futuro precisar do explode pra outras coisas.

Comment: Estou fazendo @Bacco, muito obrigado!