# Leitura de arquivo txt com múltiplas colunas para inserir em TListView

Tags: delphi

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
var
   Colunas : TStringlist;
   Item: TListItem;
begin
   Colunas := TStringlist.Create;
   Colunas.Text := StringReplace('00:46:30@21/08/2014@Carlos dos Santos@São Paulo',
      '@',Char(13)+Char(10),[rfReplaceAll]);
   Item := LV.Items.Add;
   Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[0]);
   Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[1]);
   Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[2]);
```

Ela separa por colunas usando o delimitador @, nesse caso eu coloco manualmente. Mas, eu tenho um arquivo chamado cliente.txt e dentro dele existem várias linhas do tipo:

> 00:46:30@21/08/2014@Carlos dos Santos@São Paulo
>     00:46:30@21/08/2014@João da Silva@São Paulo

Como posso ler esse arquivo, usando essa mesma função acima e colocar tudo dentro de um LISTVIEW ?

<sub>Relacionado: [Explode em Delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30813/)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Me baseei numa [resposta do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277792/916193) para propor uma maneira de ler um arquivo diretamente numa `TStringlist`, pois a lista já pode ser acessada "explodida" (usando índices).

```
var
  Linhas: TStringList;    

...

  Linhas := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Linhas.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    //Agora basta acessar as linhas com Linhas[0], Linhas[1], ..., Linhas[Linhas.Count-1]

  finally
    Linhas.Free;
  end;
```

**Aplicando a solução ao seu .txt:**

```
var
  Linhas:  TStringList;
  Colunas: TStringList;
  i:       integer;    

...

  Linhas := TStringList.Create;
  Colunas := TStringlist.Create;
  Colunas.Delimiter := '@';
  Colunas.StrictDelimiter := True;

  try
    Linhas.LoadFromFile( 'cliente.txt' );

    for i := 0 to Linhas.Count-1 do 
    begin
       Colunas.DelimitedText := Linhas[i];
       Item := LV.Items.Add;
       Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[0]);
       Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[1]);
       Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[2]);
    end;

  finally
    Linhas.Free;
  end;
```

Conforme bem apontado pelo [@Edgar Muniz Berlinck](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/405/), o código foi melhorado utilizando-se o próprio recurso da TStringList para fazer o "explode" da string (e melhorado com ajuda do [@Caputo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5536/), que lembrou do StrictDelimiter do D2006+):

Trocamos:

```
       Colunas.Text := StringReplace(Linhas[i],'@',Char(13)+Char(10),[rfReplaceAll]);
```

Por:

```
       Colunas.Delimiter := '@';
       Colunas.StrictDelimiter := True;
       ...
       Colunas.DelimitedText := Linhas[i];
```

Comment: Só para enriquecer, o TStringList possui as propriedades **Delimiter** e o **delimitedText**. Isso é bem útil para criar um **TStringList** a partir de uma string com delimitadores.

Comment: Sim, você deve setar o **delimiter** e depois o **delimitedText** no lugar do **text** com **replace**.

Comment: @Bacco, so tem um problema nesse segundo codigo, quando o cliente tem espaços, ele não funciona, tipo Carlos dos Santos, ele só captura o Carlos.

Comment: @Bacco, com a versao DelimitedText, do modo "antigo" funciona perfeito...

Answer (score 2):

.Você pode usar o seguinte código para fazer isso.

Dessa forma fica mais elegante é eficiente.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Coluna, Linha: string;
  Colunas: TArray<string>;
begin
  Linha:= '00:46:30@21/08/2014@João da Silva@São Paulo';

  Colunas:= Linha.Split( [ '@' ] );

  for Coluna in Colunas do
    ShowMessage( Coluna );
end;
```

O Split é um `Helper` do tipo de dado `string`.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split

Existem outros métodos `Helper` no tipo de dado `string`. Digite `Ctrl + Espaço` depois da variável para ver os demais métodos.

Comment: Boa saída a do Split também! Seria legal aplicar oItem.SubItems.Add( ... etc no seu exemplo, para valorizar a resposta.